# Encountering HTTP/502 Error When Passing Emojis in Druid SQL Query via Scala Play Framework and JDBC

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, druid

I'm facing an issue in my Scala Play Framework application that uses JDBC to send SQL queries to Druid. When I attempt to execute a Druid SQL query containing emojis (e.g., ) using prepared statements, I encounter an HTTP/502 error. The specific error message is:

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute HTTP Request, got HTTP/502."

versions:
*play-framework: 2.8.16

java: 11

druid: 25

avatica-core: 1.17.0*

Here's a API response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "id": "83h6dee8l",
        "requestId": 1,
        "exception": {
            "title": "Execution exception",
            "description": "[SQLException: while preparing SQL: SELECT added, comment FROM sample_data_test WHERE (__time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2009-10-24 00:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2023-10-25 00:00:00') AND comment IN ('SHAE_BAE_BIIHHH', 'test comment') GROUP BY added, comment, channel ORDER BY lower(channel) DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0]",
            "stacktrace": [
                "java.sql.SQLException: while preparing SQL: SELECT added, comment FROM sample_data_test WHERE (__time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2009-10-24 00:00:00' AND TIMESTAMP '2023-10-25 00:00:00') AND comment IN ('SHAE_BAE_BIIHHH', 'test comment') GROUP BY added, comment, channel ORDER BY lower(channel) DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:56)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.Helper.createException(Helper.java:41)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:358)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:175)",
                "at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337)",
                "at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java)",
                "at v2.druid.DruidQueryServiceImpl.$anonfun$getQueryDataV2$1(DruidQueryServiceImpl.scala:53)",
                "at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:180)",
                "at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.withConnection(Databases.scala:174)",
                "at v2.druid.DruidQueryServiceImpl.getQueryDataV2(DruidQueryServiceImpl.scala:46)",
                "at v2.druid.DruidQueryController.$anonfun$getData$11(DruidQueryController.scala:41)",
                "at scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:678)",
                "at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$Transformation.run(Promise.scala:467)",
                "at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)",
                "at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)",
                "at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.scala:18)",
                "at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:94)",
                "at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:100)",
                "at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49)",
                "at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)",
                "at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)",
                "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute HTTP Request, got HTTP/502",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.send(AvaticaCommonsHttpClientImpl.java:131)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteService.apply(RemoteService.java:34)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.JsonService.apply(JsonService.java:124)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta$12.call(RemoteMeta.java:241)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta$12.call(RemoteMeta.java:237)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.invokeWithRetries(AvaticaConnection.java:793)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.RemoteMeta.prepare(RemoteMeta.java:236)",
                "at org.apache.calcite.avatica.AvaticaConnection.prepareStatement(AvaticaConnection.java:354)",
                "... 22 more"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the druid log:

> org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374

```
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Request begin HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Request headers HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3
router           | User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.20.1)
router           | Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
router           | Content-Length: 374
router           | Content-Type: application/octet-stream
router           | Via: 1.1 c9d73fa9f3a2
router           | X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.192.1
router           | X-Forwarded-Proto: http
router           | X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:8888
router           | X-Forwarded-Server: 192.168.192.8
router           | Host: 192.168.192.9:8082
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpContent - Advanced content to last chunk java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=390 cap=390]
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,465 DEBUG [qtp213850519-111] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - queue ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=0/6,p=1}@542acfc3 startThread=0
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Generated headers (-1 bytes), chunk (-1 bytes), content (390 bytes) - NEED_HEADER/HttpGenerator@4c4c177{s=START}
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,465 DEBUG [qtp213850519-121] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - run ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=0/6,p=1}@542acfc3 in QueuedThreadPool[qtp213850519]@cbf1997{STARTED,68<=68<=68,i=61,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=0/6,p=1}]
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,465 DEBUG [qtp213850519-121] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor - ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=1/6,p=1}@542acfc3 started
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,465 DEBUG [qtp213850519-121] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor - ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=1/6,p=0}@542acfc3 waiting
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,466 DEBUG [qtp213850519-118] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor - ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=0/6,p=1}@3b859d06 task=EatWhatYouKill@6d80e411/SelectorProducer@45f0038/IDLE/p=true/QueuedThreadPool[qtp213850519]@cbf1997{STARTED,68<=68<=68,i=61,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=1/6,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=0]@2023-11-14T11:33:17.466Z
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,466 DEBUG [qtp213850519-118] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@6d80e411/SelectorProducer@45f0038/IDLE/p=true/QueuedThreadPool[qtp213850519]@cbf1997{STARTED,68<=68<=68,i=61,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=1/6,p=0}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=0]@2023-11-14T11:33:17.466Z tryProduce true
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,466 DEBUG [qtp213850519-118] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - updateable 0
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator - generateHeaders POST{u=/druid/v2/sql/avatica/,HTTP/1.1,h=10,cl=390} last=true content=HeapByteBuffer@6a77fca[p=0,l=390,c=390,r=390]={<<<{"request":"prepare","con...ET 0","maxRowCount":-1}>>>}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator - User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.20.1)
router           | Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
router           | Content-Length: 374
router           | Content-Type: application/octet-stream
router           | Via: 1.1 c9d73fa9f3a2
router           | X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.192.1
router           | X-Forwarded-Proto: http
router           | X-Forwarded-Host: localhost:8888
router           | X-Forwarded-Server: 192.168.192.8
router           | Host: 192.168.192.9:8082
router           |
router           |
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,467 DEBUG [qtp213850519-118] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - updates 0
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,467 DEBUG [qtp213850519-118] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint - Key interests updated 1 -> 0 on SocketChannelEndPoint@c49370f{l=/192.168.192.9:8082,r=/192.168.192.8:59946,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=29/300000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@6493274f[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@1eee9d27{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@35214ae4{s=HttpChannelState@2d3a7ac5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,467 DEBUG [qtp213850519-118] org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector - Selector sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl@4e99f5f5 waiting with 1 keys
broker           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,467 DEBUG [qtp213850519-111] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill - EatWhatYouKill@6d80e411/SelectorProducer@45f0038/IDLE/p=true/QueuedThreadPool[qtp213850519]@cbf1997{STARTED,68<=68<=68,i=61,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@517fbf62{s=0/6,p=1}][pc=0,pic=0,pec=1,epc=0]@2023-11-14T11:33:17.465Z m=EXECUTE_PRODUCE_CONSUME t=CEP:SocketChannelEndPoint@c49370f{l=/192.168.192.9:8082,r=/192.168.192.8:59946,OPEN,fill=FI,flush=-,to=28/300000}{io=0/0,kio=0,kro=1}->HttpConnection@6493274f[p=HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1},g=HttpGenerator@1eee9d27{s=START}]=>HttpChannelOverHttp@35214ae4{s=HttpChannelState@2d3a7ac5{s=IDLE rs=BLOCKING os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=1,c=false/false,a=IDLE,uri=null,age=0}:runFillable:BLOCKING/BLOCKING
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,460 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Request failure HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3
router           | org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateHeaders(HttpGenerator.java:637) ~[jetty-http-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:239) ~[jetty-http-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP$HeadersCallback.process(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:217) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241) ~[jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223) ~[jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP.sendHeaders(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:65) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:212) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.send(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:84) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.send(HttpChannel.java:128) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:233) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP$Delegate.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:260) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:122) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpDestinationOverHTTP.send(HttpDestinationOverHTTP.java:38) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:381) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:336) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:315) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:309) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:286) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:263) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.send(HttpClient.java:600) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.sendAsync(HttpRequest.java:778) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:765) ~[jetty-client-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.AbstractProxyServlet.sendProxyRequest(AbstractProxyServlet.java:618) ~[jetty-proxy-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.sendProxyRequest(AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.java:429) ~[druid-services-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.proxy.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:114) ~[jetty-proxy-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.doService(AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.java:381) ~[druid-services-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.service(AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.java:292) ~[druid-services-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:791) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1626) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.security.PreResponseAuthorizationCheckFilter.doFilter(PreResponseAuthorizationCheckFilter.java:82) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.initialization.jetty.StandardResponseHeaderFilterHolder$StandardResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(StandardResponseHeaderFilterHolder.java:161) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.security.AllowHttpMethodsResourceFilter.doFilter(AllowHttpMethodsResourceFilter.java:78) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.security.AllowOptionsResourceFilter.doFilter(AllowOptionsResourceFilter.java:75) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.security.AuthenticationWrappingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationWrappingFilter.java:57) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.security.UnsecuredResourceFilter.doFilter(UnsecuredResourceFilter.java:60) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.apache.druid.server.security.SecuritySanityCheckFilter.doFilter(SecuritySanityCheckFilter.java:77) ~[druid-server-0.23.0.jar:0.23.0]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501) ~[jetty-servlet-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:763) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277) ~[jetty-server-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311) ~[jetty-io-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105) ~[jetty-io-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104) ~[jetty-io-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336) ~[jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313) ~[jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171) ~[jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:135) ~[jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882) [jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036) [jetty-util-9.4.40.v20210413.jar:9.4.40.v20210413]
router           |      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_275]
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - queue org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender$$Lambda$175/378668227@544efbcc startThread=0
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - Leaving scope org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler121597447==dftMaxIdleSec=-1 dispatch=REQUEST, async=true, session=null, oldsession=null, oldsessionhandler=null
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c-187] org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool - run org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender$$Lambda$175/378668227@544efbcc in QueuedThreadPool[AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c]@ae3c140{STARTED,8<=8<=100,i=2,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@625264ed{s=1/8,p=0}]
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c-187] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Request shutdown output HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - handled=true async=true committed=false on HttpChannelOverHttp@127f3859{s=HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=HANDLING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=READY awp=false se=false i=true al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=//localhost:8888/druid/v2/sql/avatica/,age=10}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - unhandle HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=HANDLING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=READY awp=false se=false i=true al=0}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - nextAction(false) READ_CALLBACK HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=HANDLING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - action READ_CALLBACK HttpChannelOverHttp@127f3859{s=HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=HANDLING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=HANDLING,uri=//localhost:8888/druid/v2/sql/avatica/,age=10}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.apache.druid.server.AsyncQueryForwardingServlet.2db86a7c - 646294277 proxying content to upstream completed
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c-187] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Request abort HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3 HttpExchange@282ccdc6{req=HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3[COMPLETED/org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374] res=HttpResponse[null 0 null]@71340f1[PENDING/null]} on HttpChannelOverHTTP@23ced3d3(exchange=HttpExchange@282ccdc6{req=HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3[COMPLETED/org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374] res=HttpResponse[null 0 null]@71340f1[PENDING/null]})[send=HttpSenderOverHTTP@26ce6841(req=FAILURE,snd=FAILED,failure=org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374)[HttpGenerator@4c4c177{s=END}],recv=HttpReceiverOverHTTP@64c2a36b(rsp=IDLE,failure=null)[HttpParser{s=START,0 of -1}]]: {}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - unhandle HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=HANDLING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState - nextAction(false) WAIT HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=WAITING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c-187] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange - Terminated request for HttpExchange@282ccdc6{req=HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3[TERMINATED/org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374] res=HttpResponse[null 0 null]@71340f1[PENDING/null]}, result: null
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c-187] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Terminating request HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - action WAIT HttpChannelOverHttp@127f3859{s=HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=WAITING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=WAITING,uri=//localhost:8888/druid/v2/sql/avatica/,age=10}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [qtp633514467-64] org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel - !handle WAIT HttpChannelOverHttp@127f3859{s=HttpChannelState@3e025170{s=WAITING rs=ASYNC os=OPEN is=IDLE awp=false se=false i=false al=0},r=2,c=false/false,a=WAITING,uri=//localhost:8888/druid/v2/sql/avatica/,age=10}
router           | 2023-11-14T11:33:17,461 DEBUG [AsyncQueryForwardingServlet-2db86a7c-187] org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender - Response failure from request HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3 HttpExchange@282ccdc6{req=HttpRequest[POST /druid/v2/sql/avatica/ HTTP/1.1]@1da392d3[TERMINATED/org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374] res=HttpResponse[null 0 null]@71340f1[COMPLETED/org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374]}
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to handle emojis in Druid SQL queries within the context of Scala Play and JDBC.

I have verified that the same query works fine without emojis, but as soon as emojis are included, the error occurs. I'm using Postman for testing.
It's worth noting that when I directly paste the same query containing emojis into Druid, it works perfectly fine. The issue seems to be specific to the interaction between Scala Play, JDBC, and Druid.

Answer (score 0):

Error that sticks out to me in the broker log is:

> 500: Incorrect Content-Length 390!=374

Does it still happen with a [later Avatica](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/api-reference/sql-jdbc)?

Suggest maybe putting this as a [Github Issue](https://github.com/apache/druid/issues) on the main repo, together with a sample of the query that fails. Noting that Druid 28 just came out, so you may want to see if you get the same issue on a different Druid version. You could spin up the 28 env at https://github.com/implydata/learn-druid and create a dummy query.